# what to use for this requirement, Array, List, Map,?

Tags: java, arrays, list, hashmap

While making my program i have come across this requirement that i have to assign unique id's to some Objects that i create. Now i am creating the objects dynamically on GUI, and initially i used simple counter to assign int value to the created node, and it worked just fine.

However the problem that this approach creates is that if while creating the GUI, if some node has to be deleted, this id is also removed and is never used again. With the next new node, everytime i have to use the latest counter value and this creates lot of missing int values if nodes are deleted during the process.

I wanted to reuse those missing id's upon creating of new nodes, for this i am confused which approach i should addopt.

**MY Ideas:**

1. Using a ArrayList that contains the available values, plus if a node
   is deleted, it's id is added to this list, i sort this list and use
   the minimum value for new node. Fine but, when i use this value, if
   i remove it from List, the index is not deleted and this causes
   problem.
2. HashMap, similarly like above i add available id's and remove not used, but not sure how to sort this hashMap???

Can you suggest how i should go about it? May be i need some kind of stack where i can push values, sort it and use the minimum value, and if that i used, it is removed from this stack, please give some ideas about this how to accomplish this task???

Comment: Is there any practical benefit to re-using missing id's, or just for fun?

Comment: @mellamokb, just a cosmetic issue otherwise id's are still unique and no problem, but just incase if it is easy i would like to do it

Comment: Is there any practical consequence to gaps in your id space?  You `aren't` storing them in an array, are you?

Comment: @mellamokb, that's an excellent point.  Databases don't assign numeric keys by trying to reuse old identifiers.  Unless there's a good reason, it'd be a lot more efficient to increase everytime and that's all.

Comment: @911TurboS even if there's an easy way to do it, unless you have a really good reason, you're still wasting resources to reassign deleted id's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep a list of the deleted IDs, and when you create a new node, check that list for an ID to re-use (doesn't matter which you take); if the list is empty (as it will be initially), get a new ID "the old way".  Even more clever: make the list an object that will generate a new ID if there aren't any deleted ones in it, so the caller doesn't have to worry about HOW the ID was arrived at.

Comment: +1.  Probably how I'd do it, assuming there were some great importance in reusing ids.

Comment: that's more then what i wanted, i'll give this a try now

Comment: thanks this is what i used, i simply call getID() and it works, ended up using ArrayList containing deleted Id, and if it is empty simply use the counter value, works perfectly, thanks again ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) (which automatically sorts all entries added from least to greatest) to store the deleted id's (`myTreeSet.add(old_id)`).  That way, when you go to create a new instance, you would check to see if there are any entries in the `TreeSet` first.  To grab the lowest value, you would use `myTreeSet.first()` (which should be an `O(1)` operation).  If the `TreeSet` is empty, which means all known id's are currently in use, then you would go ahead and use the next available id as normal.

Comment: thanks i am also going to look at this, haven't used before sounds very promising approach

Answer (score 1):

How about a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) to store the used IDs? You could then use [`higher(0)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#higher%28E%29) to find the lowest free ID. If it returns `null`, then you know that you have no used IDs.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution works fine only if you have few nodes! Imagine an application with thousands nodes! What about memory consumption?
The Hashmap solution is better to you aims and need less controls.

Comment: yes but the nodes will map to actual physical nodes and they are of the order of 20-30 at max, in our testbed, so it is not a big problem

Comment: Infact more resource wasting problem would be to scan the whole scenario to find out deleted/missing id's :)

Comment: The point is! How often you have to access the ArrayList? If you have to repeat an operations one time per execution is ok! Ten thousands time is too much overhead! You have to check both memory and cpu usage!